# INKSCAPE - Create a circle in three colors

Tags: inkscape

I need some help here creating a circle :)

What I am trying to do is create a circle in 3 colors.  from 0 deg to 119 Red,  120 to 239 white, and the rest Blue.  There is no fill in the circle and the stroke is 20px.

I thought the way to go would be to create a red circle and duplicate it into white and blue circles.  From there use the Path menu (Union, Intersection...) on the three circles so the the proper color would appear in the proper place.  That does not seem to be getting the results that I want.

How can I accomplish creating a circle using 3 colors?

Comment: So basically a pie chart?

Comment: More like a pie crust, no filling.  Trying to create a circle, not a sphere.

Comment: For future reference, that would be a donut chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Ellipse tool, with the tool option along the top set to "Switch to arc (unclosed shape)"

[image]

Create three circles, copied and pasted in place, set a different coloured stroke on each.

Move the arc end points as you wish.

[image]

Comment: You can set the angles numerically, too, in the 'Start' and 'End' fields at the top, @JohnW.

Comment: @Moini - yes you can!